# How to check or print padding done in python (keras)?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, padding

While making a model, we use padding in Conv2D function and also Maxpooling function like :

```
Conv2D(filters=52,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same')
```

Is there a means of check the padding done or printing its size or the padding itself so as to facilitate debugging ?

Answer (score 2):

The exact way how the padding is computed can be found in the github code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/82c65f264797b41e3f93e390d3bc1fec9857b719/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L33-L133).
First the output width and height values are computed and then the padding:

For `padding="SAME"`:

```
out_height = ceil(in_height / stride_height)
out_width  = ceil(in_width / stride_width)

if (in_height % strides[1] == 0):
    pad_along_height = max(filter_height - stride_height, 0)
else:
    pad_along_height = max(filter_height - (in_height % stride_height), 0)
if (in_width % strides[2] == 0):
    pad_along_width = max(filter_width - stride_width, 0)
else:
    pad_along_width = max(filter_width - (in_width % stride_width), 0)
```

You can also get an idea about the padding by using a convolution with a kernel that consists of ones:

```
import tensorflow as tf

dummy_in = tf.ones([1, 6, 6, 1])
kernel_size = 3
strides = 1
padding = "SAME"

conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 
                              kernel_size, 
                              strides=strides, 
                              padding=padding, 
                              use_bias=False,
                              kernel_initializer=tf.ones)
# build layer
conv(dummy_in)

# subtracting the number of pixels in kernel gives
# the number of pixels that were padded
kernel_size**2 - conv(dummy_in)[...,0]
```

This outputs

```
[[[5., 3., 3., 3., 3., 5.],
  [3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3.],
  [3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3.],
  [3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3.],
  [3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3.],
  [5., 3., 3., 3., 3., 5.]]]
```

where each entry corresponds to the number of pixels that were padded in a single convolutional window. As you can see, 5 pixels where added around the corners, and 3 pixels at the sides. In this case, the image was padded by one row/column  of zeros at each side.